# How to replace vector tidier

Tags: r, vector, model, deprecated, broom

I am looking to find another function that can replace the `broom::tidy()` function after it get removed. Here is what the broom package warning says:

*Tidy Atomic Vectors
Vector tidiers are deprecated and will be removed from an upcoming release of broom.*

Here is a description of function:

*`tidy()` produces a `tibble()` where each row contains information about an important component of the model. For regression models, this often corresponds to regression coefficients. This is can be useful if you want to inspect a model or create custom visualizations.*

Thanks you,

John

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the warning, there is no general deprecation of the function `broom::tidy`, this warning only occurs when it is called with an atomic vector. In this case `tibble()` seems to be a slot-in replacement:

No deprecation warning for tidy() when called for a linear model:

```
library(broom)
fit <- lm(Volume ~ Girth + Height, trees)
tidy(fit)
## A tibble: 3 x 5
#  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 (Intercept)  -58.0       8.64      -6.71 2.75e- 7
#2 Girth          4.71      0.264     17.8  8.22e-17
#3 Height         0.339     0.130      2.61 1.45e- 2
```

#Deprecation warning:

```
tidy(1:5)
## A tibble: 5 x 1
#      x
#  <int>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
#4     4
#5     5
#Warning messages:
#1: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
#See help("Deprecated") 
#2: `data_frame()` is deprecated as of tibble 1.1.0.
#Please use `tibble()` instead.
```

No warning for tibble, same output :

```
tibble(1:5)
## A tibble: 5 x 1
#  `1:5`
#  <int>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
#4     4
#5     5
```

Comment: I want to apply the tidy function to a glm that has been trim in size (I removed the qr$qr data). Tidy needs the qr$qr in order to work when its call on a glm R object. My goal is to have a table lookup for the GLM coefficient estimate. How can I reproduce that regardless the function tidier atomic vector will be remove in future release of the broom package ? Thank you

Comment: If you've got a specific use case in mind, you'll need to create a minimal reproducible example to show the example - perhaps starting with my first example would make a clear example.

Comment: Your above example is good, if you add this line of code before tidy fit$qr$qr <- NULL

Comment: Then I don't get the warning, but an error about the dimensions, that's why I was hoping you'd add an example that demonstrates your issue

Comment: You can use the same example and output you have describe in your post and remove the qr$qr portion of your model.

Answer (score 1):

The deprecation warning is letting you know that the method `tidy.numeric` is being removed.

```
broom:::tidy.numeric
function (x, ...) 
{
    .Deprecated()
    if (!is.null(names(x))) {
        dplyr::data_frame(names = names(x), x = unname(x))
    }
    else {
        dplyr::data_frame(x = x)
    }
}
```

You can see the call to `.Deprecated` there, and the rest of the function just calls `data_frame`. As this function is also being deprecated, `tibble` is the new solution. As `tibble` does not honour row names, if you want to save the names, you could create something similar to the above.

```
tidy.numeric <- function (x, ...) 
{
    if (!is.null(names(x))) {
        tibble::tibble(names = names(x), x = unname(x))
    }
    else {
        tibble::tibble(x = x)
    }
}
```

Comment: Something I don't understand is that my program still working as usual regardless of the warning message. Can I ignore it ?

Comment: @JohnE. yes, the deprecation will occur in a future version of the package. You can continue using this in scripts for now. One day you will update the package and `broom:::tidy.numeric` will no longer exist. The maintainers may provide some other functionality so that the script still works but with a different named function, or perhaps it will raise an error. There is no guarantee that the your script will behave the same at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to convert a named vector as mentioned by @Miff, you can also use the function `enframe()`. It creates a tibble with two columns, one with the names in the vector and one column with the values.